# If we don't know the actual value of PI then how can we use it in formulations or rely on it for real world calculations?

Tags: soft-question, pi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do We Need the Digits of $\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73316/do-we-need-the-digits-of-pi)

Are we at best, estimating things when we use formulas involving pi to describe the area, etc. of things?

Comment: "how can we ... rely on it for real world calculations?" - In the real world, there is no such thing as a "real" circle. The wheels, cans, and other such things are approximations to the real thing; manufacturing will always give things with a few imperfections.

Answer (score 2):

Not being able to write the exact value of $\pi$ does not mean we do not know it. It has many representations.

- Some are well known, e.g. "the ratio between the circumference and the diameter of a circle",
- Others are less known, e.g. $\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{6}{n^2}}$

The use of $\pi$ in calculations made in engineering, or physics, or other "approximates" is also fine because you know *enough digits* of $\pi$ to ensure that the error margin is small enough.

Answer (score 2):

No: When we say the area of a circle with radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$, and the circumference is $2 \pi r$, those are exact.

Yes: When we say the area and circumference of a circle with radius $2$ are about $12.56637$, those are approximations.