# What is gained by computing additional digits of $\pi$?

Tags: pi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do We Need the Digits of $\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73316/do-we-need-the-digits-of-pi)

Given that at 39 digits, we have enough of $\pi$ to calculate the volume of the known universe with (literally!) atomic precision, what value is gained? Are there other formulas for which more digits of $\pi$ are useful? If so how many digits of $\pi$ do we need before there's no gain?

Comment: You mean gained besides "knowing more than 40 digits of $\pi$"?

Comment: Well, you need about 64,000 digits to cover every possible block of digits in a time ("HH:MM") or date ("MM/DD" or "DD/MM"). So, what *I* gain from knowing more than 39 digits is the foundation of my "piClock" app ---see http://piclock.com--- which actually uses the first million digits. (If there's objection to "advertising" this app here, I'll remove my comment.)

Comment: In some cases, you may need to know more than $40$ digits of $\pi$ to get $40$ digits of your answer (involving $\pi$) precise, due to error terms that blow up.

Comment: @Blue I see no need for you to remove your (very relevant) link.

Comment: The most important reason for knowing digits of $\pi$ is explained in the book/film Contact by the late physicist Carl Sagan. However you have to know it in base 11! :)

Comment: In a recent episode of Elementary, http://www.cbs.com/shows/elementary, the evil guys use digits of $\pi$ to simulate a random number generator (that gives combinations to a lock on a bank vault). The numbers look random enough to fool whatever tests they need to pass, but of course they are not random, so they can easily open the lock and rob the vault. (So, I guess, computing digits of $\pi$ can bring you --someone else's-- fortune, in a round-about way.)

Answer (score 6):

The practicality of knowing $\pi$ to so many digits has long since passed.  I think the main reason people continue to calculate its digits is because there is a certain prestige that goes along with being able to calculate more digits than anyone else.  It brings notoriety, especially when testing a new supercomputer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no practical gain in computing the circumference of a physical circle. As a matter of fact, most exercises in computing more and more digits of $\pi$ are rather some kind of computer benchmark tests (or may in fct detect computer malfunction to some extent).

In theory, it is at least feasible that a rather good approximation of $\pi$ might be needed for some intricate proof (say, of the Riemann hypothesis), but to repeat it: That would not be related to physical circle circumferences.

Answer (score 3):

The hunt for more digits of $\pi$ helps to spur research into analysis, especially in developing new methods for accelerating convergence of sums.  See, for instance, [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe](http://www.andrews.edu/~calkins/physics/Miracle.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

As per  [wikipedia: Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Computation_in_the_computer_age)

> For most numerical calculations involving π, a handful of digits provide sufficient precision. According to Jörg Arndt and Christoph Haenel, [as you point out,] thirty-nine digits are sufficient to perform most cosmological calculations, because that is the accuracy necessary to calculate the volume of the known universe with a precision of one atom.

Despite this, people have worked strenuously to compute $\pi$ to thousands and millions of digits. This effort may be partly ascribed to the *human compulsion* to break records, and such achievements with $\pi$ often make headlines around the world.

(This obsession with/compulsion to memorize/calculate more and more of the digits of $\pi$, may also, for at least a few, constitute a manifestation of [OCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder), and provide grounds for such a diagnosis!)

(To the credit of $\pi$ and its digits) ***They do have practical benefit:***

> ... such as testing supercomputers, testing numerical analysis algorithms (including high-precision multiplication algorithms); and within pure mathematics itself, providing data for evaluating the randomness of the digits of π.

...[and can be applied to test the accuracy and]

> ...the "global integrity" of a supercomputer. A large scale
>   calculation of pi is entirely unforgiving; it soaks into all parts of
>   the machine and a single bit awry leaves detectable consequences.

Answer (score 2):

I could see it to be useful to gain insight on some of $\pi$'s properties. For example, we don't know whether $\pi$ is normal or not (normal number is 'morally' a number where each digit is equiprobable in every base), so a statistical analysis of known digits may hint at that (that would not prove it, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

$\pi$ is also used to randomly generate numbers. Maybe there are some applications there too.

[π as a random number generator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26942/is-pi-a-good-random-number-generator)