# Why mathematicians attempt to find more digits for $\pi$ since it has no last digit?

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Many works and many research about irrationality of $\pi$ appear every year for predicting more digits for the tanscendental number which is $\pi$, The question that made me confused is :Why mathematicians  attempt to find more  digits for  $\pi$  since it has no last digit ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277076/what-is-gained-by-computing-additional-digits-of-pi and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73316/do-we-need-the-digits-of-pi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do We Need the Digits of $\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73316/do-we-need-the-digits-of-pi)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several reasons.

- It's suspected but not known that $\pi$ is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). Many
  digits allow for statistical tests.
- The decimal digit expansion of $\pi$ is used to test new computer hardware and software. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_PI .
- Plain curiousity. [Find youe birthday in $\pi$](http://time.com/4697605/pi-day-birthday/).
- Because we can. Here are the [first million digits](http://www.piday.org/million/).

Here's how $\pi$ starts in base $12$:

[image]